# Error during parameters parse when Spark application is submitting programically

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I would like to submit Apache Spark application to YARN programmatically (in Java, not in Scala). When I try do it (my code):

```
package application.RestApplication;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args1) {
        String[] args = new String[] {
                "--class", "org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount",
                // "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
                // "--master", "yarn",
                // "--driver-memory", "3g",
                // "--executor-memory", "3g",
                "--jar", "/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar",
                "--arg", "hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/file.txt"
        };
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args);
        Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

I get an error in line: `ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args);`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments.parseArgs(ClientArguments.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments.<init>(ClientArguments.scala:31)
    at application.RestApplication.App.main(App.java:37)
```

This is problem with parse String[] args - when array is empty program starts (but no parameters = no work). When I type the correct parameters (as above) or incorrect (eg. "--foo", "foo") I have same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are your dependencies? How do you assemble the app? What's the CLASSPATH?

Comment: This usually means there is a mismatch between the version of Scala on the server & the version your job was compiled with. Make sure they match (2.11.x for both, or 2.10.x for both)

Comment: Thank you. I changed version from 2.10 to 2.11 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928266/running-spark-application-java-lang-nosuchmethod-error), probably you've got wrong Scala version in your machine.

By the way, you can check [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy), should be good for your job :)